# R: Pass a function of many parameters as one of one parameter to another function by setting its other parameters

Tags: r, function, arguments

**General problem:**
I have a function that takes another function as an argument, of form:

```
F <- function(x, FUN){FUN(x)}
```

I could easily pass a simple function to it:

```
f1 <- function(x){plot(x, 1/x)}
F(-5:5, f1)
```

would display a plot of 1/x.

Supposing I had another, more complex function:

```
f2 <- function(x, a){plot(x, 1/x^a)}
```

`f2` has 2 arguments, so can't be passed directly to `F`.  But I might want to retain the flexibility in a so that, without defining lots of different functions, I can quickly plot `1/x^a` for whatever value of a I fancy.  I've tried, for `a = 2`:

```
F(-5:5, f2(, 2))
F(-5:5, f2(, a=2))
F(-5:5, f2(x, 2))
F(-5:5, f2(a=2))
```

But none of these work.  Does anyone have a solution?  (I could set a default for `a` in `f2`, but then I could not run it with a different value of `a`).

**Specific context:**
I have a function that will find the inverse Laplace Transform of a function, taking a function as its argument which is expected to have one argument (the Laplace variable, p).  I can invert a function like `f1` above.  But I am trying to invert a function for contaminant transport in groundwater.  This process depends upon lots of other parameters such as the water velocity and the distance being travelled.  So I would like to be able to pass a multi-parameter function for Laplace inversion in such a way that all parameters apart from the Laplace parameter p is fixed.  Ultimately I would like to do this process many times with different values for velocity etc., so I need a fluid way to change the "fixed" parameters being used.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Christopher

Comment: Have a look at `?dotsMethods` and `?do.call`. Combining the two should give you a solution.

Comment: What about using ellipsis `F <- function(x, FUN, ...){FUN(x, ...)}; F(-5:5, f2, a=4)`?

Comment: Curry is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a generator of function:

```
genFunc = function(a)
{
    function(x) plot(x, 1/x^a)
}

F(-5:5, genFunc(2))
```

Or use `Curry` from `functional` package to fix parameters you want and spice your meals:

```
library(functional)
F(-5:5, Curry(f2, a=2))
```

Comment: Thank you Colonel Beauvel.  Both solutions simple and effective.

Comment: No problem, Curry is higher level and let you write less code :)